# Batch file run command after previous command has finished executing

Tags: java, batch-file, weblogic, wlst

I am trying to clear a batch file, which does some Weblogic Admin server data source update after which I need to restart the admin server..I am trying to automate the same through batch file...So I have;

```
call wlst UpdateDataSource.py
stopWebLogic.cmd weblogicUser weblogicPwd localhost:7001
startWebLogic.cmd
```

Now, how do I ensure that startWebLogic.cmd is executed only after the previous line has finished executing (i.e. after stopWebLogic.cmd finishes)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming Windows, since you have `.cmd` files!?

You can use `&` between the scripts to run them in sequence. If you use `&&` the ensuing scripts will only run if the previous ones completed successfully.

You can [read more here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx).

Cheers,